# Matrix multiplication renders different results when converting from MATLAB to python

Tags: python, matlab, code-conversion

I have an `MxN` matrix `A` where `A` is complex and apparently has some properties which renders a diagonal matrix for `A'*A`. `A` is also very large (256x16384) so I cannot think of a way to upload it here for reproducing.

In the MATLAB code, I have:

```
imshow(abs(A'*A),[]);
```

this produces the following image:
[image]

The converted code in python:

```
tmp=np.dot(A.T,A)
plt.imshow(np.absolute(tmp))
plt.show()
```

produces:

[image]

The diagonal seemed to rotate. Is there any reason for this rotation? Am I doing the conversion correctly?

Comment: Plot the axis of the matlab one. Note how (0,0) is top left. Also do provide a [mcve]. I am sure you can provide a 3x5 matrix that reproduces this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you're confusing between the transpose and the conjugate transpose operator.

**Matlab to Python:**

[transpose](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html):

- Matlab: `A.'`
- Python: `A.T`

[conjugate tranpose](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html):

- Matlab: `A'`
- Python: `A.conj().T`

So change your matlab code or your python code according to your need.